# Spayed cat recovery question

Tags: cats, defecation

I got my cat spayed now three days ago. She has been wearing a [buster after surgery outfit](https://www.ebay.com/p/KRUUSE-Buster-Bodysuits-for-Cats-Outfit-XXS-13-5-in/2055897354?_trksid=p2047675.l2644) !instead of a collar. Today on the morning I noticed that she was not wearing the outfit anymore. I was very shocked as the outfit is pretty tight that how did she manage to take it off and it wasn't even open. Now I am worried that she has been licking her wound. I checked it but couldn't tell if it's swollen or infected.

Also she haven't pooped for now 3 days and she still have ate. When should I get worried?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you need to ask the vet if putting  on a cone on your cat is an alternative to the buster and ask your vet about the cat not using the litterbox for 3 days.

it is likely your cat have post sugery pain so ask your vet about getting some painkiller for your cat(NEVER EVER GIVE PAINKILLERS MENT FOR HUMANS TO YOUR CAT OR OTHER PETS).

it is not good for your cat to stress and trying to get rid of the buster so you have to find a solution to this,maby a tighter fit will do the trick.

it is best to stop your cat from licking  the wound but it is not very dangerous as cat saliva is anti bacterial,the problem is the stitches might become loose.